# MODX can't save <base href="[[!++site_url]]" />

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Whenever I try to save `<base href="[[!++site_url]]" />` into a chunk the page pauses - the data won't save and I get a JS error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.mask.addClass is not a function

This is on 2.6.5 on a fresh install.

Would anyone know what I could and how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was Mod security enabled on server, after asking hosting provider to disable it, everything went fine

Answer (score 0):

In older MODX versions there was a problem sometimes generating and saving content of this tag. It may depend on server settings or MODX version, could you update to 2.8.4 for example? Also as an option (if you do not have a multi-context site, although this option is also possible with it) you can explicitly directly specify domain in the form (if it works for you of course):

`<base href="https://yourdomain.com" />`

Answer (score -1):

You got a ! in the `<base href="[[!++site_url]]" />` try removing it

Comment: I tried, but that shouldn't make a difference - just non-caching indicator.